# How to update data in form in angular 2?

Tags: angular

So I have a form with some data that comes from a server.

If the form is changed, I show 2 buttons: save and cancel. On save the new data is sent to the server, and on cancel I need to roll the data back to the previous state. I thought it might be simple to just make a get request to the server, but it seems to not working.

```
        import { ContactService } from './../-services/contact.service';
    import { Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
    import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
    import {FormsModule} from "@angular/forms"
    import { MatSnackBar } from '@angular/material/snack-bar';

    @Component({
      selector: 'contact',
      templateUrl: './contact.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./contact.component.scss'],
      providers: [ContactService]
    })
    export class ContactComponent implements OnInit {

      contact;
      userID;
      ischanged = false;

      constructor(
        private Router: Router,
        private Route: ActivatedRoute,
        private cs: ContactService,
        public snackBar: MatSnackBar
      ) { }

      ngOnInit() {
        this.userID = this.Route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
        this.getContact();

      }
      getContact() {
        this.cs.getContact(this.userID)
        .subscribe(res => {
          let userArr = [res.json()];
          this.contact = userArr[0]; // тут потом чекнуть, а то слегка бред с массивом
          console.log(this.contact);

        });
      }

      changed(x) {
        this.ischanged=!this.ischanged 
      }

      update(contact) {
        this.cs.updateContact( contact )
        .subscribe(res => {
          console.log(res)
          alert('updated')
        })


      };
      openSnackBar(message: string, action: string, duration: number) {
        this.snackBar.open(message, action, {
          duration: duration,
        });
      }
      delete(){
        this.cs.deleteContact( this.userID )
        .subscribe(response => {
          console.log(response);
          this.openSnackBar('Контакт был удален', 'OK', 5000);
          this.Router.navigate(["../list/contact"])
        });
      }
      abort() {

        alert('data rolled back');

      }
    }
```

And this is my template

```
        <div class="contact">
      <div class="cc">
        <div class="c_content">
          <div class="c_header">
            <p class="c_header-name">{{contact?.name}} </p>
            <p class="c_header-company">{{contact?.company.name}} </p>
            <button mat-icon-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu" class="c_header-menu">
              <mat-icon>more_vert</mat-icon>
            </button>
            <mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
              <button mat-menu-item (click)="delete()">
                <mat-icon>delete</mat-icon>
                <span>Удалить</span>
              </button>
            </mat-menu>
          </div>
          <mat-tab-group>
            <mat-tab label="Tab 1">
              <form class="c_info" #f="ngForm" id="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="update(f.value)">
                <!-- begin cc_item -->
                <div class="cc_item">
                  <div class="cc_item_label">
                    <span>Имя</span>
                  </div>
                  <div class="cc_item_value">
                    <input maxlength="100" ngModel="{{contact?.name}}" name="name" #name="ngModel" (change)="changed(name)" value="{{contact?.name}}">
                  </div>
                </div>
                <!-- end cc_item -->
                <!-- begin cc_item -->
                <div class="cc_item">
                  <div class="cc_item_label">
                    <span>Фамилия</span>
                  </div>
                  <div class="cc_item_value">
                    <input maxlength="100" ngModel="{{contact?.username}}" name="username" #username="ngModel" (change)="changed(username)" value="{{contact?.username}}">
                  </div>
                </div>
                <!-- end cc_item -->
                <!-- begin cc_item -->
                <div class="cc_item">
                  <div class="cc_item_label">
                    <span>Телефон</span>
                  </div>
                  <div class="cc_item_value">
                    <input maxlength="100" ngModel="{{contact?.phone}}" name="phone" #phone="ngModel" (change)="changed(phone)" value="{{contact?.phone}}">
                  </div>
                </div>
                <!-- end cc_item -->
                <!-- begin cc_item -->
                <div class="cc_item">
                  <div class="cc_item_label">
                    <span>Email</span>
                  </div>
                  <div class="cc_item_value">
                    <input maxlength="100" ngModel="{{contact?.email}}" name="email" #email="ngModel" (change)="changed(email)" value="{{contact?.email}}">
                  </div>
                </div>
                <!-- end cc_item -->
                <!-- begin cc_item -->
                <div class="cc_item">
                  <div class="cc_item_label">
                    <span>Компания</span>
                  </div>
                  <div class="cc_item_value">
                    <input maxlength="100" ngModel="{{contact?.company.name}}" name="companyname" #companyname="ngModel" (change)="changed(companyname)"
                      value="{{contact?.company.name}}">
                  </div>
                </div>
                <!-- end cc_item -->
                <!-- begin cc_item -->
                <div class="cc_item">
                  <div class="cc_item_label">
                    <span>Адрес</span>
                  </div>
                  <div class="cc_item_value">
                    <input maxlength="100" ngModel="{{contact?.address.city}}" name="addresscity" #addresscity="ngModel" (change)="changed(addresscity)"
                      value="{{contact?.address.city}}">
                  </div>
                </div>
                <!-- end cc_item -->
                <!-- begin cc_item -->
                <div class="cc_item">
                  <div class="cc_item_label">
                    <span>Вебсайт</span>
                  </div>
                  <div class="cc_item_value">
                    <input maxlength="100" ngModel="{{contact?.website}}" name="website" #website="ngModel" (change)="changed(website)" value="{{contact?.website}}">
                  </div>
                </div>
                <!-- end cc_item -->
              </form>
            </mat-tab>
            <mat-tab label="Tab 2"> some text </mat-tab>
          </mat-tab-group>
        </div>
        <div class="cc_btn_group" [ngClass]="{'active':ischanged}">
          <button mat-raised-button color="primary" form="ngForm">АГОНЬ!</button>
          <button mat-raised-button type="button" (click)="abort()">Отмена</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="c_tasks">
        <tasks></tasks>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I think you should need to use Angular Reactive Forms https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms

Answer (score 0):

try this method: keep old values for cancel changes

```
  contact: any;
  oldContact: any;

  getContact() {
    this.cs.getContact(this.userID)
      .subscribe(res => {
        let userArr = [res.json()];
        this.contact = userArr[0]; // тут потом чекнуть, а то слегка бред с массивом
        this.oldContact = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(userArr[0])); // тут потом чекнуть, а то слегка бред с массивом
        console.log(this.contact);

      });
  }

  abort() {
    this.contact = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.contact));
    alert('data rolled back');

  }
```